# ARDL time series steps

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root, ardl

I want to confirm that regarding Auto-Regressive Distributed Lag model used for time series all variables must be stationary at level or at 1st difference and no variable should be at 2nd difference.

Now my d.v and main i.v are stationery at level. However, I have 4 other control variables/explanatory 3 of them are stationery at 1st difference.

Now for the variables that are stationery at 1st difference, do I to need convert their values to 1st difference before using them in ARDL?

Comment: ARDL does this automatically in EVIEWS or STATA